# Where did this risk exposure 'estimation-formula' come from?

Tags: estimation, forecasting, standard-deviation, risk

I was reading a book and the authors metioned that risk exposure can be estimated *scientifically* using this forumula:

$risk(\$)  = \frac{(a + 4m + b)}{6}$ and standard deviation $\sigma = \frac{b-a}{6}$

Where:
a = minimum dollar exposure
m = most likely dollar exposure
b = maximum dollar exposure

Where `a, m, b` are solicited from past data or expert judgement.

All this is fine, but I've never seen this formula - where did this come from? Is it founded in statistics or any scientific reference? Anyone know anything about this? Pointers/suggestions/clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

I'm curious as to how does the above formula provides a risk exposure metric. Why '6' in the denomiator and why the `a + 4m + b` in the numerator? Similarly for $\sigma$? Any ideas?

**EDIT**: This formula seems to be that of weighted averaging but am not sure about it's inception or the reason of giving 'm' a weight of 4 and how that influences the calculation of $\sigma$?

**UPDATE**:Book - Making the Software Business Case. However just Googling for the numerator threw up a few results - it seems to be known as the [PERT formula](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/project-management/use-pert-technique-for-more-accurate-estimates/120) and is used for estimation of 'time' - but my question about the 'formula' still holds irrespective of it being used for risk...

**DERIVATION OF FORMULA** - The reason for the formula to be what it is seems to be beautifully explained in a [JSTOR article](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2632222?uid=3739560&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=56114458413) for those interested!

Comment: You could help us by specifying the book and providing its definition of risk!  This word "risk" means so many things that it's practically impossible to reverse-engineer a formula like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Three Point Estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_estimation) sometimes used in project management.  It is a rule of thumb used to translate simple estimates from non-statisticians into helpful statistics.

Rather strangely, the estimate of the mean comes from assuming a so-called [double-triangular distribution](http://www.mhnederlof.nl/doubletriangular.html), where $m$ is both the median and the mode, so with density

- $f(x) = \frac{x-a}{(m-a)^2} \text{ when } a \lt x \lt m$
- $f(x) = \frac{b-x}{(b-m)^2} \text{ when } m \lt x \lt b$

but the estimate of the standard deviation is rather less than this distribution might suggest.

Comment: It has a name ;) Thanks for the pointer. However I still left wondering "why" that particular selection of weights? i.e. why 4m and not 7m why not 2a or 7b etc.? Any theoretical grounds for this formula?